# colorControlNormal is not applied to MaterialToolbar's icons

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

I want to theme my MaterialToolbar so that all its icon's colors are resolved to the value `?attr/colorOnPrimary` (#FFF). I **don't** want to have to set `android:theme` directly in the XML layout file. Instead, I want to be able to override `toolbarStyle` attribute to control the theming (as per recommended in the [Material Design page](https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-top)).

These are the relevant attributes of the theme that my app uses.

```
<style name="Base.Theme.GithubUser" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.GithubUser.Toolbar</item> <!-- I want to control all the styles (themes) of my MaterialToolbar through this attribute -->
</style>
```

The style I'm using (`@style/Widget.GithubUser.Toolbar`) is as follows.

```
<style name="Widget.GithubUser.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    ...
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.GithubUser.Toolbar</item>
</style>
<style name="ThemeOverlay.GithubUser.Toolbar" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_toolbar_icon_highlight_color</item>
</style>
```

What I have now is: my overflow icon is indeed tinted with `?attr/colorOnPrimary` but my other icon is not affected. I tried changing `colorControlNormal` to other color values and the overflow icon does change according to the value supplied to the attribute, but my other icon is not affected at all. Here's the display.

[image]

For reference, this is my `menu.xml` file that is used to inflate the toolbar menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_navigate_to_favourite_fragment"
        android:title="@string/show_favorites_text"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawable_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_settings"
        android:title="@string/change_language_text"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

The icon that is erroneously displayed is `@drawable/drawable_favorite` and it is an SVG file. Its content is as follows.

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="412.735"
    android:viewportWidth="412.735" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M295.706,35.522C295.706,35.522 295.706,35.522 295.706,35.522c-34.43,-0.184 -67.161,14.937 -89.339,41.273c-22.039,-26.516 -54.861,-41.68 -89.339,-41.273C52.395,35.522 0,87.917 0,152.55C0,263.31 193.306,371.456 201.143,375.636c3.162,2.113 7.286,2.113 10.449,0c7.837,-4.18 201.143,-110.759 201.143,-223.086C412.735,87.917 360.339,35.522 295.706,35.522z"/>
</vector>
```

**What I have tried and worked**: changing the `path android:fillColor` of the SVG to `?attr/colorControlNormal`. Ideally, I don't want to tamper with the SVG `fillColor` property and just be able to set a tint to the drawable through `colorControlNormal`. Where did I get the theming wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in your vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ..
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
       ....
</vector>
```

[image]

Just a tip: in your style you can use:

```
<style name="Widget.GithubUser.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary</item>
</style>
```

or if you want to extend it just use:

```
<style name="Widget.GithubUser.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.GithubUser.Toolbar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.GithubUser.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_toolbar_icon_highlight_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `colorControlNormal` is not tinting the vector and I have to instead tint the vector directly? (The Material Design page specified that Action Icons can be tinted using that attribute by theming and not direct SVG file manipulation.)

Comment: *To your tip*. But I'm changing `colorControlHighlight` through my customized ThemeOverlay. I can't customize `colorControlHighlight` if I don't at least extend the original style (i.e. `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary`). Did you mean extending that style as a parent to my customized style instead?

Comment: @Richard in that case in `ThemeOverlay.GithubUser.Toolbar` just set `parent ="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"`.

Comment: Okay, I've done the extension part. What about `colorControlNormal`? Why is it not tinting the drawable icon based on the value of that attribute with my drawable, but it is **indeed** tinting the overflow icon correctly? If possible, I'd like to avoid tinting each vector individually and instead apply a tint through theming to the whole toolbar icons.

Comment: Quite long to explain in a comment. But did you check the overflow icon? It has `android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"`

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know that the overflow icon has that attribute set: that explains why setting `colorControlNormal` works on the overflow icon and not on my uploaded SVG resource. If you don't mind me asking, how can I view the overflow icon's file (I'd like to see the `android:tint` attribute directly)?

Comment: @Richard You can navigate with Android Studio through the style looking for: `actionOverflowButtonStyle` . Or check the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/res/drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material.xml)